How to make a pill with a groove?
How to make a pill with a groove?
I don't know if the groove can be made in the end or it should be made before.



What is "the end" and what is "before"?  Make it before what?

It's difficult to provide a general answer with multiple forms provided as reference without teaching all available modelling techniques, which is obviously not practical because we are talking about 3d modelling in general. Maybe watch some beginner modelling tutorials online to get familiar with modelling tools. There are many tutorials available. You should be familiar with all modelling tools from the Mesh, Vertex, Edge, Face menus as well as selection tools and transform operators at least. You learn what techniques to use by practicing and modelling different forms. That takes time.

There is no right answer to the question about how you should start or end your model - whatever works for you is fine. For this specific model you can do it many ways and most of them will be fine.
You could start with a filled( F ) circle or a cylinder and connect some verts( J ) to make lines matching the groove:

Then bevel( Ctrl  +  B ) the edges going around and move( G   ->   Z ) the middle line down:

(I also inserted an additional edge loop with  Ctrl  +  R  as you can see, but that depends on the exact form you are after)
Connect some more verts to make some new edges:

and after that you can bevel some more edges to make them rounder:

Your sample images are very different though, so you would model them differently. It's helpful to know what you are modelling before you start so make a chioce.
It's also fine to start with whatever shapes you want to have on the tablet and then make a circle around and connect the geometry or you could use booleans and then tidy the topology after. It's helpful to think about how vertices are going to match and what end result topology you want to have from the start in that case. There are many ways.
